# Rendering a screenshot of onely one selected application in a (docker) containter

Tags: docker, container

In this there is for me three questions :

- How to render a graphical application -ex firefox, in command line ? Without the entire screen.
- How to render a console output -ie, only text ? I see screenshot or re-writing the text and rendering an image from it with some colors. It can be nice to use the fewer 3-rd party packages possible and be fast.
- Which package the container need to install to be able to "display" graphical applications, if any ?